# How to solve this error?about node.js

Tags: node.js

this is the source code

[image]

this is the  error message

[image]

when this code run on windows,it throws the following error message,

you can see it in picture 2 ,how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ENOENT signal means "No such file or directory". You are trying to spawn a program named 'prg' which does not exist or cannot be found.